# Span click function not working (awesome font star rating system)

Tags: jquery, html, function, click, font-awesome

coders.

I'm trying to make a simple photogallery with a star-based rating system.  I'm using the example offered on W3, using Font Awesome, for the job.  However, this is non-responsive, and I want the user to be able to change the rating by clicking on stars.  IE if he clicks the fourth star, it will become four stars, etc.

The problem is, my click function is non-responsive.  Looking further, it seems the problem is that the span tag doesn't have anything inside it.  Is there a way around this, or do I have to use something other than font-awesome to get a responsive star-rating system?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en-us">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bomb Defuser</title>

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <style>
 .checked {
   color: orange;
 }

 img {
 height:400px;
 width: 400px;
 }

 span {
 display:inline;
 }
 </style>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
 awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>


  <img src = "camera.png"></img>
 <br>
 <div id = "rating1">
 <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
 </div>
 <hr>
 <br>
 <br>


 <img src = "bomb.png"></img>
 <br>
 <div id = "rating2">
 <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
 </div>
 <hr>
 <br>
 <br>



 <img src = "dummy_image.png"></img>
 <br>
 <div id = "rating3">
 <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
 </div>
 <hr>
 <br>
 <br>


 <script>
 //now what I'm trying to do, is say if you click the nth child of a div, so 
 //does it and all previous children.
 //the number that represents the n in nth can be like the array.length is 
 //in a for loop.
 //okay, first thing is first.  We have to set up an onClick event.

 $("span").click(function(){
     $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });


  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: define " responsive star-rating system"

Comment: Meaning that if a user clicks the fourth star, for example, it and the first, second, and third star all become orange.

Comment: see my answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `index()` to get the current star index and the `:lt` pseudo-selector to select the previous stars

```js
$('.fa-star').click(function(){
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('.checked').removeClass('checked');
    $('.fa-star:lt('+(i+1)+')').addClass('checked');
});
```

```css
.checked {color:orange};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <div id = "rating1">
 <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
 <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First you have to give different id in each span tag. Like this :

```
<span id="first" class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span id="second" class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span id="third" class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<span id="fourth" class="fa fa-star"></span>
<span id="fifth" class="fa fa-star"></span>
```

Then , fire its click event. Like following :

```
  $("#first").click(function(){
       alert("first start is clicked")       
  });
```

May be it is worked.